# how to choose python version accordingly in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

In last project, I used python 2.7. The new one have to run in python 3.5 so I installed 3.5. I choose Python 3.5 in Setting-->Python interpreter, and I got `Error : Django is not importable in this environment.`
Then I tried to run

```
 pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

It seems that something wrong with the path, and how could I make it right?

Comment: Use the project interpreter settings to create a new virtual environment with Python 3.5 and *install Django in that*, either through PyCharm's GUI or by running the `activate` script virtualenv generates in your terminal. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-virtual-environment.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html (if you aren't certain what you're doing, it's probably easier to stick entirely within PyCharm to start).

Comment: `pip install django` is for python 2. Please use `pip3 install django` for python 3

Answer (score 2):

Just go with `pip3` suited for Python 3x envs:

```
   pip3 install Django
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the pip command points to python2.7 version of pip, and as django is already installed for python 2.7, you are getting the message you mentioned.

You need to install django for python3.5. To do that, either directly run pip executable inside python3.5 folder, or choose python3.5 as the interpreter from pycharm, and install django through the ui of pycharm.

Depending on how you installed python3.5, you could also run

```
pip3.5 install django
```

from the console to invoke python3.5 version of pip